# DataContractSerializer - Not Deserializing Child List - List<T>

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML using DataContractSerializer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>
  <header>
    <cust>1</cust>
    <bill>2</bill>
    <ship>3</ship>
    <nbr>123456</nbr>
  </header>
  <details>
    <detail>
      <nbr>123456</nbr>
      <part>1227</part>
      <qty>2</qty>
    </detail>
  </details>
</order>
```

I'm having difficulty deserializing the child `<detail></detail>` segment, which is always `null`. My class structure is as follows:

```
[DataContract(Name = "order", Namespace ="")]
public class Order
{
    [DataMember(Name = "header", Order = 0)]
    public Head head { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "details", Order = 1)]
    public Details details { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
    }
}

[DataContract(Name = "header", Namespace ="")]
public class Head
{
    [DataMember(Name = "cust", Order = 0)]
    public string customerNbr { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "bill", Order = 1)]
    public string billNbr { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "ship", Order = 2)]
    public string shipmentNbr { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "nbr", Order = 3)]
    public string orderNbr { get; set; }

    public Head()
    {

    }
}

[DataContract(Name = "details")]
public class Details
{
    [DataMember(Name = "detail", Order = 0)]
    public List<Detail> DetailList { get; set; }

    public Details()
    {
        this.DetailList = new List<Detail>();
    }
}

[DataContract(Name = "detail")]
public class Detail
{
    [DataMember(Name = "nbr", Order = 0)]
    public string orderNbr { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "part", Order = 1)]
    public string partNbr { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "qty", Order = 2)]
    public decimal orderQty { get; set; }

    public Detail()
    {

    }
}
```

And in my main program, I'm reading the XML document and deserializing it using the following:

```
XDocument readDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
Order createOrder = null;
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Order));
createOrder = (Order)ser.ReadObject(readDoc.CreateReader());
```

What can I do to make the detail segment deserialize correctly?

Comment: I guess this `<qty>2</ord>` is just a typo in your xml sample right? Or else that could definitely give some headaches.

Comment: @KarelTamayo great catch! Indeed that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your data contract classes are different from the ones the actual xml structure requires.

You can solve this by making a small modification to your models.

#### Set the Namespace for `Detail` class to match the one in the other classes,  i.e.: a blank value.

```
[DataContract(Name = "detail", Namespace = "")]
public class Detail
{
    //same stuff here...
}
```

#### Make your Details class a collection to the data contract.

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "details", Namespace = "")]
public class Details : Collection<Detail> { }
```

You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts) for more details about collection and data contract serialization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already had Namespace = "" for Detail class, missed it in the question. But CollectionDataContract() fixed it for me. You saved the day!